# Why can not I properly parse JSON on Angular4?

Tags: angular

```
getPrefectures() {
     return this.http.get(this.PREFECTURE_API);
}

this.addressService.getPrefectures().subscribe((response) => {
    this.prefectureData = response.json();
    this.updatePrefecture();
});

updatePrefecture() {
    for (let d of this.prefectureData) {
        console.log( d)
    }
}
```

I getting JSON from the API in a general way for Angular, but the result is as follows.

[image: 1]

Next is JSON raw data.

[image: 2]

How can we get the data correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: Do not use images to provide code or other textual stuff. However, you do not pass the body of the response, do you?

Comment: I'm sorry, I will be careful next time.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved.

```
this.prefectureData = JSON.parse(response.json());
```